# Rodar função addslashes em todos os campos do insert

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou usando o código em PHP abaixo para fazer um insert no banco de dados MySQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO acolhidos
(
situacao,
nome,
dataNasc,
nacionalidade,
naturalidade,
cidadeNasc,
cpf,
...
updateLogin
)
VALUES
(
'$dados[situacao]',
'$nome',
'$dataNasc',
'$dados[nacionalidade]',
'$dados[naturalidade]',
'$dados[cidadeNasc]',
'$dados[cpf]',
 ...
'$_SESSION[cc_login]'
)";
$acolhido = mysqli_query($conn->link, $sql);
```

Sendo que a lista completa de campos inseridos é por volta de 80, então eu listei acima apenas alguns campos como exemplo.

Para evitar que, nos campos do tipo String, o INSERT falhe caso o usuário tenha inserido caracteres do tipo aspas simples (') ou duplas (") na entrada do formulário, eu estou usando a função addslashes em todos os campos do tipo string antes de montar a string do insert, conforme abaixo:

```
$dados['aspectoFisico'] = addslashes($dados['aspectoFisico']);
$dados['aspectoEmocional'] = addslashes($dados['aspectoEmocional']);
$dados['aspectoPsiquico'] = addslashes($dados['aspectoPsiquico']);
$dados['aspectoSocioCom'] = addslashes($dados['aspectoSocioCom']);
$dados['outrasObservacoes'] = addslashes($dados['outrasObservacoes']);
```

Ou seja, eu estou tendo que repetir a mesma função para quase todos os campos do meu insert.

Então eu gostaria de saber se há uma forma mais prática de rodar esta função addslashes em todos os campos do meu insert antes de executar o comando SQL?

Ou talvez uma forma de rodar o addslashes diretamente na minha string $sql sem danificar o conteúdo do comando sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz um `foreach()` antes para adicionar o `addslashes()`:

```
foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
    $dados[$key]=addslashes($value);
}
```

Comment: no caso acima, o addslashes não danifica a variável se ela for numérica ou se for uma data? Porque alguns dos campos do array $dados serão do tipo numério ou date.